# NodeJS: async / await why is my variable not being added to the object

Tags: json, node.js, object, async-await

I have an app that writes JSON files based on API requests and I would like to add a timeStamp to the objects I gather and rearrange.

So I get a complete request that finally get into a "transformer" to adapt the data to the layout I want which looks like this:

```
// Own Modules
var getSingleTicker = require('./getSingleTicker').getSingleTicker;
var getServerTime = require('./getServerTime').getServerTime;

async function transformTicker(ticker) {
  var result = {};
  var timeStamp = {};
  var timeStamp = await getServerTime();
  Object.keys(ticker).forEach((k) => {
      result= {
        name: k,
        a: ticker[k].a,
        b: ticker[k].b,
        c: ticker[k].c,
        v: ticker[k].v,
        p: ticker[k].p,
        t: ticker[k].t,
        l: ticker[k].l,
        h: ticker[k].h,
        o: ticker[k].o,
        n: timeStamp,
      }
      console.log(`[ADDED]: ${JSON.stringify(k)}`);
    // });
  });
  return result;
}

module.exports = {
  transformTicker,
}
```

So as you can see, the function should wait for the timeStamp request's result and append afterwards the timeStamp to each result (there are various requests being made) as 'n'.
However, when I do that, the timeStamp prints to the console:

> [ADDED]: "XLTCZUSD" {"unixtime":1501573081,"rfc1123":"Tue,  1 Aug 17
>   07:38:01 +0000"} [ADDED]: "XXRPZUSD"
>   {"unixtime":1501573084,"rfc1123":"Tue,  1 Aug 17 07:38:04 +0000"}
>   [ADDED]: "DASHUSD" {"unixtime":1501573085,"rfc1123":"Tue,  1 Aug 17
>   07:38:05 +0000"} [ADDED]: "XZECZUSD"
>   {"unixtime":1501573084,"rfc1123":"Tue,  1 Aug 17 07:38:04 +0000"}
>   [ADDED]: "XXBTZUSD" {"unixtime":1501573080,"rfc1123":"Tue,  1 Aug 17
>   07:38:00 +0000"} [ADDED]: "XREPZEUR"
>   {"unixtime":1501573197,"rfc1123":"Tue,  1 Aug 17 07:39:57 +0000"}

but doesn't get written into the JSON. The writing occurs in the main (app.js) and then there are a bunch of modules that request > collect and ultimately transform the info from the REST Api.

Here's the main:

```
async function worker() {
      var tickerList = await getTickerList();
      var tickerInfo = await getTickerInfo(tickerList);
      var filename = `./modules/batches/${new Date().toISOString()}batch.json`;

      fs.writeFile(filename, JSON.stringify(tickerInfo), (err) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log("[SUCCESS]: All tickers processed successfully!");
      });
  }

  worker();
```

tickerList = an array of tickers to lookup for

The full requests starts with the following module:

```
// Own Modules
// var tickerList = require('./getTickerList');
var getSingleTicker = require('./getSingleTicker').getSingleTicker;

  function getTickerInfo(tickerList) {
    if (tickerList) {
      console.log('[SUCCESS]: Initiating the process');
      return Promise.all(tickerList.map(getSingleTicker));
    } else {
    console.log('[FAILED]: There was a problem importing the list.');
    }
  }

module.exports = {
  getTickerInfo,
}
```

Then to the getSingleTicker one:

```
// Own Modules
const getFromApi = require('./getFromApi').getFromApi;
const transformTicker = require('./transformTicker').transformTicker;

function getSingleTicker(tick) {
 return getFromApi('Ticker', {pair: tick})
      .then(transformTicker).catch((error) => {
console.log('[FAILED]: ', error);
  });
}

module.exports = {
  getSingleTicker,
}
```

and finally to the transformTicker (where I'm trying to add the timeStamp).
The time stamp comes from:

```
var getFromApi = require('./getFromApi').getFromApi;

function getServerTime() {
  return getFromApi('Time').then((res) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log('[ERROR]: ', error);
  });
}

module.exports = {
  getServerTime,
}
```

You can find the whole project here: https://github.com/Ardzii/mongoNode

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: `result= {...}` overwrites the `result` in the `Object.keys(ticker).forEach((k)` loop.

Comment: Hey Alex! Yes, I need it because there are several requests being made to the server and each needs to get back into my new layout. I get all the information correctly into the JSON except for the timeStamp ==> n.

Comment: Works fine for me https://repl.it/JruA/1, apart from double declaration of `var timeStamp`, but I believe it's not the issue.

Comment: That's weird... why doesn't it for me? Maybe because the timeStamp in my version is an object as well? Would this have to do with anything... ? 
As for the `var timeStamp` double I added it afterwards to check if that could be problematic but indeed this is a useless repetition...

Comment: You can change timestamp to the object in the repl.it code. Play with it until you get a reproducible error. It will be your [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Current edition of the question is off-topic as  'can no longer be reproduced'. There must be something you forgot to mention in the question. As a side note, did you notice that even tho getFromApi returns 2 keys k1 and k2, you get only k2 at the end?

Comment: Hey Alex! I will find what messes everything up and come back here once my error can be reproduced. As for the k2 mention of your comment... that's weird again since in my code I get all 25 objects returned to the JSON.

Comment: Well, it might be the case I got it wrong and the mocks return something different from what the real responses are. You can modify them to better reflect reality. Or it might be a typo in the code you posted here.